# Kafka consumer process order with concurrency

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a producer writing to a Kafka topic with 100 partitions, and it choose the partition by the user ID, therefore user's messages are necessarily being processed by the order they were submitted to the queue.

The service which is responsible for consuming has 2-10 instances, each one has in its configuration:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency=10
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.partitioned=true
```

I recently noticed that although the consumer **start** to process the partition messages in order, sometimes one message is done before the one after it because it's easier to being processed than next one.

It's important to me to maintain the current processing rate of the service, and because I'm not familiar with the threading model of spring cloud stream I wanted to consult and ask for other's knowledge. What is the best way to ensure that one user's message is being processed only after the previous ones are done?

--*EDIT*--

As requested, more relevant params.

- Kafka version: 0.10.2.1
- spring-cloud-stream version: 1.1.0.RELEASE

binder params:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOnError=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq=true
```

consumer configuration as printed to the console:

```
2018-12-11 09:56:51,975 [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] INFO  [AbstractConfig::logAll] - ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = true
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = consumer-11
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    max.poll.records = 2147483647
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    group.id = 
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
```

producer config as printed to the console:

```
2018-12-11 09:56:52,439 [-kafka-listener-1] INFO  [AbstractConfig::logAll] - ProducerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    max.block.ms = 60000
    interceptor.classes = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = producer-5
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    acks = 1
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    retries = 0
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    compression.type = none
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    timeout.ms = 30000
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    ssl.key.password = null
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    batch.size = 16384
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    max.request.size = 1048576
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    linger.ms = 0
```

Comment: As long as you don't hand off to another thread within your application, messages in a single partition will be processed in the order in which they appear in the partition.

Comment: I know, but does it mean that message number 2 will start being processed only when message number 1 is committed? Because that's my goal

Comment: That is correct a consumer for a particular partition will invoke the listener on one thread.

Comment: What happens in case the consumer polls 10 messages from the broker and has 10 threads? won't they work at the same time? I guess the messages will be assigned to the threads by their order, but how can you prevent a race condition?

Answer (score 1):

The partitions are distributed across the container threads.

If the container concurrency is 10 and you have 20 partitions, each consumer (thread) will normally be assigned 2 partitions.

This guarantees delivery order within a partition.

Comment: Thank you. What happens in case you have more threads than partitions?

Comment: ok. Can it be a commit configuration then? maybe it waits until all of the messages from the poll are done and then commit? Can that cause my problem?

Comment: What version of Spring Cloud Stream are you using? What you are suggesting is impossible as long as the listener runs entirely on the consumer thread. Perhaps your partitioning strategy is flawed. You should add debug logging to show the user id and partition of each message to track this down. Edit the question to show **all of your configuration properties** and your listener.

Comment: I added producer and consumer configurations. The partition strategy is fine, one user's messages are going to the same partition

Comment: You mentioned a listener, did you mean the consumerRebalanceListener?

Comment: No; I meant the stream listener code; I meant show all your `spring.cloud.stream` configuration. You didn't say what version you are using. If all messages are going to the right partition then, as long as the listener runs completely on the consumer thread, it is impossible to receive messages out of order.